# Grabbing <tr> with Simple HTML Dom based on inner text of <th>, but <th> has no attributes

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I have a HTML which look like this, and I am trying to use simple HTML DOM to grab the Name value and Nickname value.

```html
<tr>.....</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<td>John</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><span>Nickname</span></th>
<td>Johny</td>
</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
```

I am having difficulties as the th and td does not have id or classes

so i tried using innertext value with the following php code

```php
require_once('lib/simple_html_dom.php');
$url='http://123.com';
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach ( $html->find ( 'tr th' ) as $element ) {

if ($element->innertext = 'Name'){

    $element = $element->parent;

    $tinfo = $element->find ( 'td', 0 );

    $info = $tinfo->plaintext;

    echo $info;}
}

$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach ( $html->find ( 'tr th span' ) as $element ) {

if ($element->innertext = 'Nickname'){

    $element = $element->parent;

    $tinfo = $element->find ( 'td', 0 );

    $info = $tinfo->plaintext;

  echo $info;}
}
```

I could not seems to get the above code to work any advice on this? How do i accomplish this?

Comment: A side question: What do you want to achive with the use of th tag within a table body?

Comment: the ''equals to'' operator does not look right on your if statement but i doubt that is causing the problem

Comment: Dear reporter, I am trying to scrape the value of td base on the value of th in the same tr

Comment: Switch to [this lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory), then do: `$html->find('th[text=Name] + td')` - much cleaner, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing some conflicting scripts, My new code, as advised by Ghost, now works for scraping name and nickname value

```php
<?php
$name = $nickname ='';
foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr) { // each row
    foreach($tr->childNodes() as $tdh) { // each cell of that row
        if($tdh->tag == 'th' && $tdh->innertext == 'Name') {
            $name = $tdh->next_sibling()->innertext;
        }
    }
}

echo $name;
foreach($html->find('tr th') as $tr) { // each row
    foreach($tr->childNodes() as $tdh) { // each cell of that row
        if($tdh->tag == 'span' && $tdh->innertext == 'Nickname') {
            $nickname = $tdh->parent->next_sibling()->innertext;
        }
    }
}

echo $nickname;
?>
```

Credit to Ghost for the answer.